# How to print the directory which is 1 level up in groovy?

Tags: groovy

May I know how to print the directory path which is 1 level up? (eg. the groovy file is located in "abc/def/ghi/dummy.groovy" and I want to get the "abc/def" path)

here is my dummy.groovy script

```
File fileCon= new File("/../")
logger.debug((String.format("[%s]", fileCon))
```

Answer (score 1):

groovy file could be loaded from plain file, from jar, from url.

i'd not recommend to use this approach - it will not work for all cases.

```
def url = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()?.getLocation()
println new URL(url, '..')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get the parent directory as `File`:

```
def file = new File('abc/def/ghi/dummy.groovy')
println "Parent: ${file.getParentFile().absolutePath}"
```

it will give you `abc/def/ghi/`. You may get parent folder from the result:

```
println "Parent: ${file.getParentFile().getParentFile().absolutePath}"
```

you'll get your desired `abc/def`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any File in GroovyDocs, so I presume this is a Java Class.
So why not just use:

```
def file = new File('abc/def/ghi/dummy.groovy')
def filePath = file.getParent().getParent()
```

Comment: Why not just read the existing answers before writing another one? ;) You don't bother to read the existing answers, do you? ;)

Comment: I do read them tho, they all looks promising, but I just typed what I first thought...
It's silly I didn't think twice, sry about that :)